# Unable To FIlter DataTable by Unit Category

Tags: javascript, laravel, yajra-datatable

Problem Statement:
I'm facing an issue with filtering a DataTable based on the "Unit Category" column. I want to be able to click on a category in the menu and filter the DataTable to show only the rows that belong to that category.

Expected Behavior:
When I click on a category in the menu, the DataTable should be filtered, showing only the rows with the selected category in the "Unit Category" column.

What I've Tried:
I have implemented a DataTable with server-side processing. I've added a custom column "unit_category_name" to the DataTable using the addColumn method in my controller. In my JavaScript code, I'm trying to use the table.column('unit_category_name').search(categoryName).draw(); function to filter the DataTable, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Code Snippets:

Controller:

```
public function uomDatas()
{
    $uoms = UOM::query();

    return DataTables::of($uoms)
        ->addColumn('unit_category_name', function ($uom) {
            return $uom->unit_category->name;
        })
        ->addColumn('action', function ($uom) {
            return $uom->id;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['unit_category_name', 'filter', 'action'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let table = $('.uom-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/unit-category/uom-datas',
        },
        columns: [
            // ... other columns ...
            {
                data: 'unit_category_name',
                name: 'unit_category_name',
                searchable: true
            },
            // ... other columns ...
        ]
    });

    // Search
    $('#uom-search').on('keyup', function () {
        table.search(this.value).draw();
    });

    // Filter by unit_category
    $('#filter_uom_by_cate').on('click', '.menu-link', function () {
        var categoryName = $(this).text().trim();
        table.column('unit_category_name').search(categoryName).draw();
    });
});
```

I'm not getting any error messages in the console. The filtering simply doesn't work when I click on a category in the menu.